# Questions About Core Data Parent/Child Context Concurrency Concept on Master/Detail Application

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an application that uses Master Detail.

The Master will show list of activities and will show the detail of each activity on Detail upon click. On Detail, the activity detail can have some selections from Core Data records and user also can create and save object in selection. Selected object from selection will be passed back to detail, and when user Save, save the detail, else, discard the details.

Following is the illustration:

[image]

Using the parent/child context Core Data concept (I am on learning stage though). 
How can I manage this?

I am thinking of these:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *masterMOC =
    [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
NSManagedObjectContext *detailMOC =
    [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
NSManagedObjectContext *selectiondMOC =
    [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

detailMOC.parentContext = masterMOC;
selectiondMOC.parentContext = detailMOC;
```

Is it the correct way?

**Currently**, I am using this way:

I init each different contexts for Master and Detail, and pass Detail's context to Selection:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = ((AppDelegate*)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).persistentStoreCoordinator;
_detailContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_detailContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
```

However, this will result the detail will be also saved when user save on Selection.

Comment: Why do you want multiple contexts? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Since if I have 1 single context, while inserting a record on selection, my detail will be also saved.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is not so good. You should not have two main queue contexts. You could make the `masterMOC` a background one and use it for, say, saving in the background.

Much better: just use one context in your app to start with until the need for background contexts arises.

In any case, you need to use **one context**, the main thread one, for both the master list and the detail view because both are shown in the UI at the same time.

Comment: If I use one context only, then when user save in selection list, the detail will be also saved. While if I use 2 different contexts (not using the concurrency context) between detail and selection and pass back selection object to detail, it will popup merge error when I save the detail.

Comment: I don't see a problem with two main queue contexts if one of them is a "disposable" editing context. It makes committing or discarding the editing changes very simple - though they have to be single-use - create when editing begins, destroy when it's done.

Comment: @jrturton Right. I thought in the current use case (display, edit) a single context would be better and certainly simpler for OP describing himself to be in the "learning stage".